# Jquery animation help

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to animate two divs widths at the same time (one increasing, one decreasing) so that the parent containers overall width remains exactly the same.

As an example, a container div contains 5 child divs.  Teh container div is 1000px wide and 4 of the child divs are 150px wide and another is 400px.  I want to be able to animate the 400px div down to 150px and one of the 150px divs up to 400px;

The problem I am getting is that the parent container shrinks and expands as the animation completes - and it happens noticeable.

I am not looking for a plugin or anything for this, simply some advice on the best way of achieving this.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:

The main problem is that every div on the right of the one being animated gets pulled to the left and then sent back out when complete.

Here is the code I am using

```
    <style type='text/css'>
    .panel-wrapper {
        width: 954px;
        height: 372px;
        background-color: #fff;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .panel-wrapper .panel {
        margin-right: 1px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 64px;
        float: left;
        background-color: #cacaca;
    }
    #home-panel {
        width: 359px;
    } 
    .panel.last {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.panel').mouseenter(function() {
        jQuery('.panel-wrapper .open').stop().animate({width:"64px"},400, 'linear');
        jQuery('.panel-wrapper .open').removeClass('open');
        jQuery(this).addClass('open');
        jQuery(this).stop().animate({width:"359px"},400, 'linear');
    });
});
//]]>
</script>

<div class='panel-wrapper'>
    <div id='home-panel' class='panel open'>
    </div>

    <div class='panel'>
    </div>

    <div class='panel'>
    </div>

    <div class='panel'>
    </div>

    <div class='panel'>
    </div>

    <div class='panel'>
    </div>

    <div class='panel'>
    </div>

    <div class='panel last'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the animation type to linear?

Comment: I have tried setting the easing to linear already but this  hasnt made any difference

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent height to a fixed number of pixels will keep it from shrinking or expanding.

Comment: Hi, its horizontal and the divs are floated left.  Everything already has a fixed pixel width.

Comment: If the parent div is resizing then it must not have a fixed width already set.

Comment: @Chris W. It definately does have a fixed width as do each child divs

Comment: That's very strange I'm pretty sure that shouldn't be happening--if you include your code maybe we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

Include an empty div of 1000px width after the divs you want to antimate. That should keep the wrapper div from shrinking.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks but this didnt work - what was your reasoning behind this?